# Bash - how to replace nth string on mth line in a file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have an input script containing many random seeds. I want create a bash script that constantly runs my script, creates new random seeds, runs the script etc.
I know the locations of the random seeds, e.g. this is the 8th line:

```
create_atoms 1 random 650 923456 t
```

Now I would want to replace 923456 to my previously declared variable.
I guess I should use something like

```
sed -i '8s/923456/$Var/' file
```

But I can't figure out the specifics.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Use awk. It's trivial in awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the 5th word in the 8th line with GNU sed use

```
sed -E "8s/[^ ]+/$var/5"
```

For posix sed use

```
sed -E "8s/([^ ]+ +){4}([^ ]+)/\1$var/"
```

Note that `$var` must be free of special symbols like `/`, `\`, and `&` in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v line=8 -v word=5 -v value="$Var" 'NR==line{$word=value}1' file
```